# Format vue-datepicker time in yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using vue3-datepicker library.

```
      <datepicker  
      v-model="to_date"
      inputFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
       />
```

My data method is below:

```
data(){
    to_date: new Date(),
}
```

When I am selecting a date and printing `{{this.to_date}}`, it is printing in `Fri Sep 17 2021 09:39:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

I want it in yyyy-MM-dd format.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to format the date. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date#34015511

Comment: Well it's working but results only with slashes yyyy/mm/dd, I went through [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) doc, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution is to use [`Date.prototype.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), which formats the date as:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

So you get the desired date format by splitting the result by `T`, and taking the first array element:

```js
const formatDate = date => {
  const tzOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
  return new Date(date - tzOffset).toISOString().split('T')[0]
}
```

Then use the method in your template:

```html
<span>{{ formatDate(to_date) }}</span>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-date-formatter?file=src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using [moment](https://momentjs.com/) npm package

install:-

```
npm i moment
```

example:-

```
moment(new Date()).format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

you can use Use different format

```
var dt = new Date();

console.log(moment(dt).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
console.log("Date: "+moment(dt).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log("Year: "+moment(dt).format("YYYY"));
console.log("Month: "+moment(dt).format("MM"));
console.log("Month: "+moment(dt).format("MMMM"));
```